# Skip anchor element types on click

Tags: jquery, html, anchor

How to skip anchor element types on click? My goal is that if I click on a link it will call some functions but skip certain anchor element types. If a website contains links with "Skip this on click" attributes (as shown below) then clicking on it will not trigger the function. Hopefully, the example below is understandable.

https://jsfiddle.net/jo1myq8f/

```js
$('a').on('click', function() {
  // Do something
  alert("Hello! I am an alert box!");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><a href="">Do not skip</a></li>
  <li><a href="" target="_blank">Skip this on click</a></li>
  <li><a href="" class="example">Skip this on click</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Skip this on click</a></li>
  <li><a href="mailto:m.bluth@example.com">Skip this on click</a></li>
  <li><a href="tel:+123456789">Skip this on click</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: They're all anchor element types... what is the determining factor for which ones get skipped and which don't?

Comment: So what is the rule on skipping and not? If first li, do not skip?

Comment: It looks like the attributes the elements do/do not have govern the action which should be taken. Is that right? If so, that's not a robust solution, at all. Do you have control over the HTML?

Comment: The goal is that only `<a href="">Do not skip</a>` will trigger the function.

Comment: So target the element..... $("ul li:first a") why are you binding on every anchor? You really need to come up with the rules on what makes it clickable and not. So it is an empty href with no other attributes? Is it the position in the UL? What are the rules. If this was a JIRA ticket I had to work on, it would be sent back to the Product Manager asking for clarity. It is too open to interpretation.

Comment: The above list is just an example. If a website contains links with "Skip this on click" attributes (as shown above) then clicking on it will not trigger the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean based on some rules?

```js
$('a')
  .not("[target]")  // omit from selection
  .not("[class]")   // omit from selection
  .on('click', function() {
  const href = $(this).attr("href");
  if (
    href==="#" ||
    href.startsWith("mailto") || 
    href.startsWith("tel")) return;
  alert("Hello! I am an alert box!");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><a href="">Do not skip</a></li>
  <li><a href="" target="_blank">Skip this on click</a></li>
  <li><a href="" class="example">Skip this on click</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Skip this on click</a></li>
  <li><a href="mailto:m.bluth@example.com">Skip this on click</a></li>
  <li><a href="tel:+123456789">Skip this on click</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Or `$('a[href=""]:not([target], [class])')`

Comment: Sure. I wanted to make a list that was more obvious

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your answers. I found that this works as well:

HTML:

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="">Do not skip</a></li>
  <li><a href="" target="_blank">target blank (skip)</a></li>
  <li><a href="" class="skip">class (skip)</a></li>
  <li><a href="#"># (skip)</a></li>
  <li><a href="mailto:m.bluth@example.com">mailto (skip)</a></li>
  <li><a href="tel:+123456789">tel (skip)</a></li>
</ul>
```

jQuery:

```
$('a')
  .not('[target="_blank"]')  // omit from selection
  .not('[class="skip"]')   // omit from selection
  .not('[href^="#"]')   // omit from selection
  .not('[href^="mailto"]')   // omit from selection
  .not('[href^="tel"]')   // omit from selection
  .on('click', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      alert("Hello! I am an alert box!");
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jcxtd3h7/

Comment: Sure, I wanted to give various methods